# Check if a tuple contains any element of the list, python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am writing simple classifier based on lemmatization and in essence I need to check if a tuple contains any element of the list. Simple example:

```
>>> ['dog', 'bone'] in ('dog', 'cat', 'parrot')
```

returns `False` while I need it to return `True`. What is the simplest and elegant way to do that?

Comment: `any(x in b for x in a)`--the dupe should be close enough. If the lists are huge create `set`s and intersect them.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
any([val in ('dog', 'cat', 'parrot') for val in ['dog', 'bone']])
```

For actual usage, don't declare the lists and tuples inside the comprehension, as it will waste resources for no reason, you should:

```
test_list = ['dog', 'bone']
available_items = ('dog', 'cat', 'parrot')
any([val in available_items for val in test_list])
```

#### Another possible solution:

```
set(['dog', 'bone']).intersection(set(('dog', 'cat', 'parrot'))) # Would return a non empty set if there is an intersection, which translates to true.

# Use case:
if set(['dog', 'bone']).intersection(set(('dog', 'cat', 'parrot'))):
    print('intersection!')
```

Comment: @ggorlen The inner tuple isn't created multiple times. It's a constant that gets used multiple times.

Comment: Yeah, you're right--tuples are immutable but if it was a list, I think it'd be created multiple times. My mistake. Still, `any` should probably take a generator rather than a list to allow early bail, and this post is a clear dupe anyway.

Comment: @ggorlen You'll have to write it as for example `list((...))`, though, even `[...]` gets turned into a tuple constant there. I agree with the generator, of course :-)

Comment: Nice to know, thanks.